# Problem with setting cooldown for a role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make the given role of Test1 have 15 minutes of cooldown time, but the role of Test2 30 minutes
I want it to work the same as shown below, but for a given role a given cooldown

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 1800, commands.BucketType.user)
async def Test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("TEST")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never been the best with configuring cooldowns, but what I can help you with is your role detection. In order to tell if a member has a role, we're going to need a few things; the member object and the role id. It seems that you have all of those in your command context, so we should be good to write some code. I'd just reform your code to something more like this.

```
@bot.command()
async def Test(ctx):
    if any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952153496256512)]):
        pass
    elif any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952219694432326)]):
        pass
    elif any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952282198212668)]):
        pass
```